# Locate multiple strings in multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get results from a MySQL database by searching multiple terms in multiple fields. The script below is working, but not quite the way I need it and I am having trouble finding out a way of doint it.

Currently if I search for *"apples peaches"* it will return every result that has *"apples"* OR *"peaches"* on any field. I.e. if a record has *"apples"* but not *"peaches"* it will yield a result.

With the intended behavior I should get a result only if in a given record it finds all the search terms on any field. I.e. *"apples"* could be found on field f1 and *"peaches"* on field f2. If only *"apples"* is found then it is not a result.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_REQUEST['term'])) exit;
$dblink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('mytable');
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $dblink);
// query the database table for strings that match 'term'
$lcSearchVal = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);
$lcSearchVal = explode(' ', $lcSearchVal);
$sql = 'SELECT id, f1, f2, f3, f4 FROM mytable 
        WHERE (';
$parts = array();
foreach($lcSearchVal as $lcSearchWord) {
    if ($lcSearchWord <> "") {
        $parts[] = '`id` LIKE "%' . $lcSearchWord . '%"';
    }
    if ($lcSearchWord <> "") {
        $parts[] = '`f1` LIKE "%' . $lcSearchWord . '%"';
    }
    if ($lcSearchWord <> "") {
        $parts[] = '`f2` LIKE "%' . $lcSearchWord . '%"';
    }
    if ($lcSearchWord <> "") {
        $parts[] = '`f3` LIKE "%' . $lcSearchWord . '%"';
    }
    if ($lcSearchWord <> "") {
        $parts[] = '`f4` LIKE "%' . $lcSearchWord . '%"';
    }
}
$sql.= implode(' OR ', $parts) . ') order BY id desc limit 0,10';
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $dblink);
// loop through each string returned and format the response for jQuery
$data = array();
$data[] = array('value' => "", 'label' => " >> Last 10 results:", 'desc' => "");
if ($rs && mysql_num_rows($rs)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        if (strlen($row['f3']) > 250) {
            $row['f3'] = substr($row['f3'], 0, 250) . " [...]";
        }
        $data[] = array('value' => $row['id'], 'label' => $row['id'] . '/' . $row['f1'] . ' (' . $row['f2'] . ') ' . $row['f4'], 'desc' => $row['f3']);
    }
}
// jQuery wants JSON data
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
?>
```

Thank you for your input

Comment: [Please stop using `mysql_` functions](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
$lcSearchVal = 'one two three';
$lcSearchVal = explode(' ', $str);
foreach ($lcSearchVal as &$lcSearchWord) {
    $lcSearchWord = '`id` LIKE "%' . $lcSearchWord . '%" AND ';
}
$conditions = rtrim(implode('', $val), ' AND ');

echo $conditions; //returns `id` LIKE "%one%" AND `id` LIKE "%two%" AND `id` LIKE "%three%"
```

$conditions can then be inserted into the query as the WHERE condition.

Answer (score 1):

Look into doing full text indexes and queries:

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/MySQL/Getting-Started-With-MySQLs-Full-Text-Search-Capabilities/

Way better than using like statements for this kind of stuff.